# Is .NET framework 4.8 preinstalled on Windows 11

Tags: .net, .net-4.8, windows-11

My Google skills are failing me today. I'm trying to find out if .NET framework 4.8 will be preinstalled on Windows 11.

Short of downloading the beta, I was looking for a feature list for Windows 11 that would answer the question.

Comment: It's still a very early beta. It exists to answer questions like yours. Given that 4.8 is already preinstalled in Windows 10 and is the last version of .NET Old, the question becomes, `Will Windows 11 have .NET Framework preinstalled?`

Comment: I wouldn't be *entirely* surprised if Microsoft tried to use Windows 11 as a way of dropping the "old" .NET Framework entirely, instead supporting .NET 6. I haven't seen any evidence of that being the case, but I'm sure they've at least considered it.

Comment: @Josh why are you asking though? What is the real question? Do you have a desktop application you want to avoid migrating to .NET 6? Targeting an old runtime on a new OS isn't a great place to be. Trying to find out what version to target to avoid installing a runtime as well? You can solve that by using a self-contained executable in .NET 5/6.

Comment: The official source you are looking for would be [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies), but it hasn't been updated for Windows 11 yet.

Comment: I'm asking because Microsoft's support policy is based on the OS it was installed on. If they stop installing. NET Framework on a new OS, then the support window has an end date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, .NET Framework 4.8 is  [preinstalled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-48) in Windows 11.